# Loadrunner FCS bad ticket (too long value of parameter)

Tags: loadrunner

when loadrunner send a request with long string of parameter value, server returned a error: "FCS bad ticket....Truncate to 1000..."; what's the root cause of it? thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please ask your developer.  This is not a LoadRunner issue on how much can be passed.   LoadRunner has been used successfully to pass back viewstates (.Net ASPX out of control developers) of over 16MB in size - successfully without error.

Comment: Thanks， James!  i'll do that; and do you know if there any settings on FCS sever that i can modify to fix the issue?

Comment: this is checkout fucntion of a system which i recorded by Loadrunner, i just don't understand why no erros happen when manually operate on system to check out file? developer could ask the same question to me.

Comment: If it works manually, but not with your code, then you have some unhandled dynamic element in your code that needs to be addressed.  Record twice.  Compare.  Address dynamic pieces related to session, state, date, time and /or business process specific items